# valid and efficient implementation of hashcode()

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I have a class School:

```
public class School{

    private int noOfTeachers;
    private int noOfStudents;

     //setters and getters....

    public boolean equals(Object that){
     //instance of check..
      return (this.noOfTeachers == ((School)that).noOfTeachers  || 
               this.noOfStudents== ((School)that).noOfStudents);
     }


     public int hashCode(){
       //What goes in here??? o.O
     }
}
```

How should I proceed with implementation of `hashCode` for this class? I am not able to think of a strategy which will involve both `noOfTeachers` and `noOfStudents` for calculation of hash. Rather `noOfTeachers` and `noOfStudents` combination seems to be breaching contract between `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: You're right - any equality check with "or" is going to breach transitivity.

Comment: I don't see how you can. You could, of course, `return 1` - but that is next to useless as your class wouldn't work in `HashMap`s and `HashSet`s. What are you using this `equals` method for?

Comment: I think your best bet is to leave `equals` and `hashCode` alone and create a method that checks this. The reason to override those methods is so that `Collection`s respect equality using your `equals` method rather than the default which uses `==`.

Comment: What is the criteria for a `School` object to be equal to another one? I see you're returning true if either his number of Teachers or number of Students are the same, is this correct? I would think of an object to be equal to another if all of their fields are the same, not only one of them. The easiest way I see to solve this is to implement an own version of `equals(School that)`, which do the comparision between them and forget about overriding the equals and hashCode methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not find any proper `hashCode()` implementation for your class, That would serve your need! Because your `equals` method uses `OR` to its properties of your class. Using `OR` in the `equals` method returns `true` for more than one state of any object.

So using unique return value of the `hashCode()` you certainly cannot represent multiple state! And more over you should know, `hashCode()` must return unique value for an object. 
As returning multiple values by it, leads to an ambiguity (and harms certainty) to put an object into any map. Because that is a violation of the assumption of "Uniqueness of keys of a map".

Comment: This certainly doesn't work. The OP wants an `equals` method with an **or**.

Comment: if two objects are equal according to the `equals` method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the **same** result

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I request you to see the answer now, again, thanks!